# Create If branches with different scripts

Tags: mysql

I want to create a script that does different things *with different tables and commands* depending on the state of a variable. In T-SQL, I would do it like this:

```
DECLARE @whatToDo INT = 1;

IF @whatToDo = 1
BEGIN
    SELECT 1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    TRUNCATE TABLE myDumbTable
END
```

But I can't figure out how to translate this into MySQL. My goal is to create a stored procedure that either returns content from different tables, does an insert or makes an update based on the state of a parameter.

Comment: Please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: MySQL does not have the same functionality as Microsoft SQL Server concerning the execution of scripts. Within MySQL it is only possible to use if/then or case constructs within stored procedures or triggers. To define stored procedures use the syntax as mentioned by Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL you could define a stored procedure something like this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE do_something(IN whatToDo INT)
BEGIN
  CASE whatToDo
    WHEN 1 THEN 
      SELECT 1;
    WHEN 2 THEN
      TRUNCATE TABLE myDumbTable;
    -- ...
    ELSE BEGIN
      -- do something when whatToDo doesn't match any of the case branches
    END;
  END CASE;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

If you prefer, you can also write the procedure using an `IF` statement:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE do_something(IN whatToDo INT)
BEGIN
  IF whatToDo = 1 THEN
    SELECT 1;
  ELSEIF whatToDo = 2 THEN
    TRUNCATE TABLE myDumbTable;
  -- ...
  ELSE
      -- do something when whatToDo doesn't match any of the other branches
  END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: So If's aren't suitable for this kind of thing in MySQL? Case is fine for me, I'll take it, but it makes me wonder...

Comment: @noClue Absolutely you could use an `IF` statement, I just find `CASE` statements easier to read if you have a lot of branches. I've added a version that uses an `IF` statement for completeness.

Comment: Thanks! It is indeed easier to read, I was just wondering what I've been doing wrong all this time and apparently it was because I didn't use semicolons after each branch... I wish MySQL error messages were more useful. :/

Comment: @noClue yes, eventually you get to understand them but they can be confusing. But MySQL is very fussy about having statements terminated with semicolons.